# Как сделать статистику пользователей для telegram-бота?

Tags: python, telegram-bot

Мне нужно знать общее кол-во юзеров, и кол-во активных. Или одно из двух. Я пробовал `botan.io`, но с ним какие-то проблемы. Каким инструментом можно это реализовать и как это сделать?

Comment: Какие проблемы возникли с Botan?

Comment: тут множество вариантов: к примеру: простейшее логирование "увидел пользователя X" событий (с обработкой позднее) или ручное синхронное обновление базы данных  нужной статистикой при наступлении этих событий или использование своего / чужого формального event sourcing API и подписка на желаемые события.

Answer (score 0):

К примеру, Вы можете вести эту статистику записывая user id, chat id в базу, и при каждом новом сообщении от юзера обновлять поле, в которое будете писать текущее время, таким образом Вы сможете гибко управлять статистикой, самостоятельно определяя активность пользователей по времени последнего сообщения

Answer (score 0):

Для вашей статистики вам понадобится база данных с следующими полями:
`user_id` и `last_message_date`.

Также нужно определить условие "активный юзер", например, когда дата последнего сообщения была <10 дней назад.

Каждый раз, когда вы получаете `update` от `telegram-bot`, вы проверяете `user_id` на его присутствие в базе. 
Если его там нет - добавляет в базу этот `user_id` и время и дату сообщения в `last_message_date`.
Если же он там есть - обновляете поле `last_message_date` на текущее.

**Логика ваших запросов к базе:**

- Количество пользователей - FROM db SELECT COUNT(`user_id`)
- Количество активных пользователей - FROM db SELECT COUNT(`user_id`) WHERE
  (`last_message_date` < 10 дней)